# How to always select the created field when entering data into anther model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So right now in the following app, you create an event and then you get forwarded to enter student number page(another model).

I want to be able to create and event and then able to add student number to that event, without needing to select the event.

The Student and Event controllers don't have anything different. I used what the scaffold command generated.

This is the Event Model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
end
```

This is the form for Events:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :as => :input %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is the Students Model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :studentnumber, 
    numericality: { only_integer: true },
    length: { is: 8}
  belongs_to :event
end
```

This is the form for Students:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @student do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>  
    <%= f.input :event, :label => "Select Your Event", :include_blank => false %>
    <%= f.input :studentnumber, :label => "Student Number", :input_html => { :autofocus => true} %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :as => :input %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Right now when I create an event I have it forward me to the Students page and the created event is shown as a dropdown. Thus, to create a student I have to select the event and then hit submit.

I would like to always select the created event and event student-numbers in that event. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use nested resources in your route configuration for that:

```
resources :events do
  resources :students
end
```

This gives a new route for students like this: `/events/:event_id/students/new`. You can then redirect in your events controller after creating an event to the new action:

```
def create
  @event = Event.create(params[:event])

  if @event.save
    redirect_to new_event_student_path(@event)
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

In your students controller you simply need to fetch the associated event. Since all students belong to an event, you can do it in a before filter. In your new action you instantiate a new student and assign the event to it:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :fetch_event

  def new
    @student = Student.new(:event => @event)
  end

  private

    def fetch_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    end

end
```

In the student's new view the correct event should be automatically selected and you can change the event input field to be hidden.

Better on the other hand would be to drop the event input field and change the form URL to be the create route of the nested resource: `event_students_path(@event)`

For more information on routing in Rails, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: This worked for me, but now i am getting a 
No route matches [POST] "/events/21/students/new"
error 
How do i go about solving my route problem?

Comment: A redirect is always a GET, no matter what the underlying HTTP method is. So the error cannot come from the redirection. Did you by any chance use the `new_event_student_path` as URL in the form instead of the create route `event_students_path`?

Comment: I figured the redirect out, now the problem I am having is that the event is not being associated.
Eg the path should be event/10/students/20
but when i go to active admin and check what student 20 belongs to, it shows me the event is empty. 
thus i cant filter anything
any suggestions ?

Comment: You still need to assign the event manually when creating the student. So in your create action, do `@student = Student.create(:event => @event)`, just like you did it in the new action.

Comment: When i do that i get an Error 
is not a number and is the wrong length (should be 8 characters)
not sure why

Comment: ill try few more things and see when i get and if i get any more errors, Thank for the help so far.

Comment: So your validation on `studentnumber` fails. Sorry, Typed too fast, before I finished thinking. You still need to include the form parameters: `@student = Student.create(params[:student].merge(:event => @event))`. Or you could split this up in several lines: `@student = Student.new(params[:student])`, then specify the event `@student.event = @event` and finally save it `@student.save`.

Comment: ok, So the problem is, when i make the 
 <%= f.input :event, :label => "Select Your Event", :include_blank => false %>
Input hidden, The events do not want to be associated, but i think i might just keep it since when the event is created the field is auto selected, and thats why i mainly wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to send it other form. You should use accept nested attributes in Rails.

Add this in your event model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :students
 accept_nested_attributes_for :students
end
```

And in your Event controller new action

```
def new
 @event = Event.new
 @event.students.build
end
```

And in your event creation form, include your students form like this:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.fields_for :students do |s|
      <%= s.input :studentnumber, :label => "Student Number" %>       
    <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= f.actions do %>
<%= f.action :submit, :as => :input %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope it will help. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 
but this requires me to create a new event every time i want to enter a new student number, 
The purpose of this app is to just create and event and keep on adding students to that event.